# Start index cannot be larger than the length of the string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to check if a foldername doesn't have a extension.
Because I want to change the name of the folder.
But you can also change the name of a file.

And I get this error:

```
"startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.\r\nParameter name: startIndex"}
```

By this line:

```
 string newFilenameExtension = Path.GetExtension(model.FileName.Trim()).Substring(1);
```

How to check if the foldername has no extension?

Comment: `Path.GetExtension(model.FileName.Trim())` is empty because `foldername` will not have an extension. And when you using `Substring(1)` on empty string, it is throwing error.

Comment: thank you. But how to tackle then it doesnt come to that line?

Comment: `string ext = Path.GetExtension(...); if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ext)) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have code in following way -

```
string newFilenameExtension = Path.GetExtension("Sample".Trim());
string extn = string.Empty;

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newFilenameExtension))
{
      extn = newFilenameExtension.Substring(1);
}

if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extn))
{
      // Use extn here
}
```